# Dynamic Webpack require contents from folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, require

For every main `React` component I have a components folder that sits next to it. Inside each main component I have to `import` each component from the components folder separately. I'm trying to set up some code that automatically requires all of the components from the components folder into that main components file/scope/environment.

```
const app = require.context(".", true, /^\.\/.*\jsx$/)
const mainComponentFile = app('./path/to/file')
const components = require.context('./path/to/file/components', true, /^\.\/.*\jsx$/)
components.keys().forEach((x) => {
  mainComponentFile.require(x) // I know this doesn't work, my question is how can I do this?
})
```

I can see closures for each module defined in `[[Scopes]]` but I cannot access that object programatically (I've read why in other SO questions).

#### Update

I have the exact solution I was looking for and will update this question on the weekend with the answer. In short, you need to create a `Webpack` loader that changes the source by programatically placing `import` strings into it. It doesn't edit the file itself, just the code source in string format before it's sent to be compiled by webpack. The overall solution is not too complex, but for your sanity, unless you want to do something highly dynamic, go for the solution mentioned in the comments by @xadm: [babel-plugin-import-directory](http://npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import-directory)

Comment: `export * from './components';` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this would still need a script file as mentioned in @Mikkel's answer. And if so it would only load the `components` folder contents (if successful, I've only been able to do this with `require.context`), not inject them into the `mainComponentFile` lexical scope, which is what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: maybe some CLI tool, like https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/tree/906cc92eacff97e21202ed62a8bfe42012d946b1/tools

Comment: Very creative solution, but I'm really trying to find something that fits with how `Webpack` works. I've literally spent the day examining its docs, code and internal workings, pretty complex stuff inside.

Comment: You're probably looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import-directory  ... `no-unused-vars` eslint warnings?

Comment: @xadm Yeah that works, place it in an answer and I'll accept it. Its not the answer to exact problem mentioned but its the best solution (and what I've mentioned isn't possible without `Webpack hooks`, which is a really complicated solution). Essentially we're looking for simple code for a simple pattern with as little hacks as possible, and that is the solution you have provided. Thank you.

Comment: @xadm Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated. If you want the credit for the answer it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a build script that generates all the imports for you, based on the component files it finds.

You can generate lines of code like this, as long as you have a convention between filename and component name

```
export { Card } from './components/card';
export { Button } from './components/button';
```

And then you can import those to your main component, and use them as you like

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did think about this, perhaps its the better solution? I'm going to see if there is a way to do it the way I've suggested, otherwise your solution might be more straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: After a lot more research, I think this could be the right approach. But I'm going to leave this open for another two days to see if anyone solves it using the suggested approach before accepting it. Thanks!